# Correct Method to run scripts with dependencies without enqueue?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, scripts, wp-register-script

With enqueue you would change `$deps` to your script or array of scripts that are needed to run first for your script to work.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

For example:

```
function script_that_requires_jquery() {
    wp_register_script( 'script-with-dependency', 'http://www.example.com/script-with-dependency.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-with-dependency' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_that_requires_jquery' );
```

I usually do this but it doesn't always seem to work:

```
function script_that_requires_jquery(){
    if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            // jquery function goes here    
        })( jQuery );
        </script>
    <?php }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'script_that_requires_jquery');
```

Maybe this is it?

```
function script_that_requires_jquery(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            // jquery function goes here    
        })( jQuery );
        </script>
    <?php 
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'script_that_requires_jquery');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
function script_that_requires_jquery() {
    wp_register_script( 'script-with-dependency', 'http://www.example.com/script-with-dependency.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-with-dependency' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_that_requires_jquery' );
```

This is the correct method to enqueue scripts (and styles for that matter). You should **always** be using [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) to hook scripts and styles to.

There are a few thing here to check when you register scripts and styles. Firstly, make sure that the order you are placing them inside your function in is correct. The first script in the function will run first, the second second etc.. So, you cannot place your jquery dependant script before jquery, it will not work

The other potential pitfall here is [`add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action). Without setting the `$priority` parameter, there is always the danger that your script/style will be loaded **before** other scripts/styles that might overwrite yours.

In your case, your script might be loaded before jquery, so it will not work. I **always** set this parameter with a very low priority (very high number) when I add custom scripts and styles. This ensures that my scripts and styles loads dead last. So I will do something like this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_that_requires_jquery', 999 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to enqueue jquery (or any other library) before your jquery dependent code, but you also need to make sure jquery is loaded before your code is being parsed/run by the browser.